# How to add loop in tkinter label

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter, psutil

```
import  psutil
import time
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
Label = Label(root, text=psutil.cpu_percent()).pack()
time.sleep(1)
root.mainloop()
```

Here's the code. Now I want to refresh the **psutil.cpu_percent()** after 1 sec continuously. How can I make such a loop in it?

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep` when using `tkinter`. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801) will help you.

Comment: You can do it in many different ways and there are plenty of examples on the web including this site. Most of them, however, using the tkinters `widget.after(ms,func)` method to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it.
Try this.

```
from tkinter import *
import  psutil

root = Tk()
def cpu_percent():
    Label(root, text=psutil.cpu_percent()).pack()
    root.after(1000, cpu_percent)

root.after(1000, cpu_percent)    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works thanks. 

but it should be 

from tkinter import *
import psutil

root = Tk()
def cpu_percent():
    Label(root, text=psutil.cpu_percent()).pack()
    root.after(1000, cpu_percent)

root.after(1000, cpu_percent)    
root.mainloop()

Comment: Right now you are creating a new `Label` each time it loops. Try creating a `Label` and then re-configuring it with the new `text`.

Comment: In addition, the first `.after(..` seems unreasonable except you want to delay the shown output.

Comment: @TheLizzard., Thingamabobs. I don't have time to test.  I know that Label. I will try to around around.

Comment: @Jahin Ahnaf. Thank you for spotting it.